# Jewel thief in python

Tags: python

> Bonnie and Clyde are two thieves who have decided to rob a jewelry
>   story. Each has a bag they will use to carry their loot, but each bag
>   can only hold n grams of jewels before it breaks. The store they are
>   robbing has several different types of jewels, each with its own
>   weight and monetary value.
>
> - Clyde's approach to filling his bag is "greedy." This means that he adds jewels to his bag one at a time, and when selecting which jewel
>     to put in his bag next he always selects the highest valued jewel that
>     won't put him over the weight limit.
> - If Clyde ever has the choice between two jewels with an equal value but a different weight, he will always select the lighter one.
> - Bonnie thinks that if she is smarter about the way she fills her bag, she will often leave the jewelry store with a more valuable haul
>     than Clyde.  Your task is to help show that this is true. To do so,
>     you will write a program, jewelthief.py, which will take as input a
>     list of jewels (each with a weight in grams and a value in dollars)
>     and a weight limit for the bag. Your program will then output the
>     total value of the jewels in the bag when selected using the greedy
>     approach, and how that value compares with the maximum possible value,
>     which you will compute using dynamic programming. The input will be
>     given through standard input.
> - The first line of input will consist of a single integer which corresponds to the maximum weight that the bag can hold.
> - Each following line will consist of two integers and will define a new jewel type.
> - The first integer will be the weight of the jewel in grams and the second integer will be the value in dollars of that jewel.
>
> Note, you can assume that the store being robbed has an unlimited
>   number of each type of jewel.
>
> Sample Input 1:
>
> ```
> 10
> 3 4
> 2 3
> 1 1
> ```
>
> Sample Output 1:
>
> ```
> The greedy approach would steal $13 of jewels
> The optimal approach would steal $15 of jewels
> ```
>
> Sample Input 2:
>
> ```
> 575
> 125 3000
> 50 100
> 500 6000
> 25 30
> ```
>
> Sample Output 2:
>
> ```
> The greedy approach would steal $6130 of jewels
> The optimal approach would steal $12130 of jewels
> ```
>
> Sample Input 3:
>
> ```
> 1500
> 151 150
> 150 150
> ```
>
> Sample Output 3:
>
> ```
> The greedy approach would steal $1500 of jewels
> The optimal approach would steal $1500 of jewels
> ```

I am quite new to python and this question is quite confusing for me.
I am having trouble figuring how to calculate the jewel values and add up and stop at the max weight for both thieves.

Here is my code so far:

```
bag=input('max_weight of bag: ')  #weight of the bag
Clyde_value=0     #initialize weight and value for both thieves
Clyde_weight=0
Bonnie_value=0
Bonnie_weight=0
while True:
    try:
        line=input()  #input weights and values at once
    except:
        break

    if len(line)==0:
        break

    a=list(map(int,line.split(None)))
    if len(line)<1:
        break
    lst=[]
    lst.append(a)

    #print(a)  #this will printout the list below when enter the  sample input 1   
    #[3, 4]
    #[2, 3]
    #[1, 1]
    weight_jewel=a[0]  #print this will give 3 2 1 for sample input 1
    value_jewel=a[1]  #print this will give  4 3 1 for sample input 1

while Clyde_weight <= bag:   #start calculating clyde's jewel value
```

I am not quite sure if my code works well with this question. Please give me some advice and hints or an example will be great. Thank you so much.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_Problem/Python

Comment: The problem description is longer than your code. Something seems to be missing.

Comment: A program won't prove that either method is optimal. It can only show what is optimal for a particular set of data. It could disprove the assertion, however, if it had data for which the assertion was false.

Comment: What is your _specific_ problem.  That is what isn't working like you expect?  What step can't you figure out how to do?

Comment: I don't understand how to calculate and add up the jewel values and weights according to the input. Since Bonnie is looking for the best value from the jewels and Clyde(collect jewels from high to low values and prefer lighter weight), if my thought is correct. I have no idea how to start this calculation.